# Usando LoginRequiredMixin com FormView de Login

Tags: python, django, url, login

Basicamente, tenho um **FormView** onde faço validações para logar usuários em minha plataforma, caso o resultado seja positivo, o mesmo é redirecionado para a URL `/dashboard/`, como mostra o código abaixo.

```
class EntrarView(FormView):
    template_name = 'entrar.html'
    form_class = FormEntrar
    success_url = '/dashboard/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntrarView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if str(self.request.method)=='POST':
            # validações
            login(self.request, usuario)
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Esse redirecionamento está funcionando perfeitamente, no entanto, tenho **várias Views** que só podem ser acessadas se o usuário estiver logado. Para isso, estou usando o **LoginRequiredMixin**. Porém, ao realizar o login, ao invés do usuário ser redirecionado para o `success_url` do **TemplateView** (conforme segue exemplo abaixo), ele continua sendo redirecionado para o `success_url` do **FormView**.

```
class Carreiras_UsuarioView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'carreiras_usuario.html'
    login_url = '/entrar/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    success_url = '/carreiras/'
```

No meu `urls.py` tenho:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('dashboard/', views.DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('entrar/', views.EntrarView.as_view(), name='entrar'),
    path('carreiras/', views.Carreiras_UsuarioView.as_view(), name='carreiras_usuario'),
]
```

Já tentei alterar o `redirect_field_name` para `next` e `nextpage` porém não obtive sucesso, assim como setar a `success_url` do **TemplateView** para `reverse_lazy('core:carreiras_usuario')` (o nome do meu app é "core").

Lembrando que a classe **Carreiras_UsuarioView** é apenas uma de várias outras views que quero atribuir esse mesmo comportamente, isto é, dependendo va **View** que "chama" o **EntrarView**, eu quero redirecionar o usuário para a sua respectiva URL.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer com que a view seja utilizada somente se o usuário estiver logado, veja abaixo:

### Configure no settings

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_page/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

### Decore a view

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def minha_view(request):
     # código aqui...
```

Para maiores detalhes, veja [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: Mas na verdade o LoginRequiredMixin faz essa mesma função, só que ele é mais voltado para CBV...
E também não posso setar o LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL no settings pois é uma variável que vai mudar dependendo da View que que "chamar" o FormView...

Comment: vc pode passar a página de redirecionamento dentro do login_required conforme descrito na documentação `login_required(redirect_field_name='next', login_url=None)`. Independente disso, vc está usando o `redirect_field_name`? Caso não esteja retire-o e teste novamente.

Comment: Eu verifiquei a documentação do @login_required, mas conforme eu mencionei antes, só se usa ele em Function Based Views, o que não se aplica ao meu caso, já que estou desenvolvendo no padrão Class Based View. E mesmo os fields passados como parâmetro pra essa função já estão presentes nas minhas Views.

De toda forma, agradeço a resposta, ela será útil para pessoas passando por essa situação com FBV. Acabei resolvendo meu problema apenas herdando o método `get_success_url` do FormView e usando a função `self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` para identificar qual das Views chamou o login :)